# Continuously check for connection to specific URL and port

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

How do I continuously check to see if there is an active connection to a specific url and port? I am able to preform the check initially on app launch by going with:

```
const net = require('net');
const testCon = new net.Socket();

testCon.connect('12.12.123.123:8000', function () {
    // connected
});

testCon.on('disconnect', function () {
  // not connected 
});
```

How do I check if the connection is lost and reconnected. I didn't want to wrap it in a setInterval function. That seems hacky to me. There has to be a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question.  Between your 2 callbacks, there is an active connection.

Comment: Interesting. If I disconnect from my required VPN, the 'disconnect' CB doesn't fire. Likewise, if I launch unconnected, then connect the VPN.

Comment: Those actions would likely generate timeouts, which should (eventually) trigger the disconnect callback.

Comment: I see. Anyway to make this more realtime? Thanks, BTW, for the quick responses.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35510762/1136527