# Detect Websocket close connection when the users close browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am using HTML5 websocket and nodejs in my project to create a simple chat.

Everything works as it should so far.

However, I need to figure out how to detect if the the users that are connected, lost connection somehow and in particular, if they close their browser etc.

I tried the following code.

**I can successfully connect like this:**

```
wss.on('connection', function(ws, req) {

//do my stuff here/////
console.log('connection started');

});
```

However, i cannot see anything in the console when i disconnect by closing the browser.

**I use this code to detect connection close:**

```
wss.on('closed', function(ws) {
        console.log('connection closed');
});
```

Could someone please let me know if I am missing something and or doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**edit:**

This seems to work:

```
  ws.on("close", function() {
    console.log("closed");
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503895/nodejs-websocket-detect-disconnected-socket) post, the default Websocket implementation doesn't have a way to detect network disconnects, only an intentional disconnect from the user. I recommend that you try to use [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/), as it will do similar what you're looking for, and can detect disconnects. Here's an example:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(80);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User disconnected.')
    });
```

The one disadvantage to using Socket.IO is that you'll have to use a JS library on your client instead of using raw WebSockets, but you'll gain the ability to see when a client disconnects.